# SwiftUI MacOS List layout glitches when changing content order

Tags: swift, list, macos, swiftui

For ease of reproduction, I have included sample code below to fully recreate my issue.

#### The Problem

There seems to be a bug that messes up with a lists layout when changing the order of its contents, it only seems to affect MacOS in my testing.

It doesn't occur with ScrollView but in this case Its imperative that I use `List` (as I need the 'double tap to open window' functionality of navigation link that only seems to work in List)

Any workarounds or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct Book : Hashable {
    var title: String
    var description: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var books : [Book] = [
        Book(title: "Book 1", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ligula urna, vestibulum in consequat facilisis, efficitur quis quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent in ullamcorper lectus, eget accumsan nisi. Vivamus lorem ante, auctor in ultricies a, gravida id ligula. Etiam vitae ante augue. "),
        Book(title: "Book 2", description: "Ut consectetur ligula massa, in convallis diam consequat eu. Praesent nec justo blandit, posuere nisl a, consequat orci. Fusce maximus laoreet magna, ut commodo neque pellentesque eu. Aliquam condimentum urna massa, eget efficitur orci ultrices ut. Curabitur euismod feugiat mollis. Cras urna elit, varius vel lorem at, convallis tempus sapien. Integer vel purus gravida, tempus quam ac, molestie justo."),
        Book(title: "Book 3", description: "Nulla congue mi eget suscipit elementum. Donec efficitur ante id lorem fringilla tempus. Vivamus et interdum nisi.")
    ]
    
    @State var sortedBooks = [Book]()
    
    func sortBooksByTitle(){
        sortedBooks = books.sorted {
            $0.title < $1.title
        }
    }
    
    func sortBooksBytDesc(){
        sortedBooks = books.sorted {
            $0.description < $1.description
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Button(action: {
                    sortBooksBytDesc()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Sort By description")
                })
                Button(action: {
                    sortBooksByTitle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Sort By title")
                })
            }
            
            List{
                
                ForEach(sortedBooks, id: \.self) { book in
                    VStack{
                        Text(book.title)
                            .font(.title)
                        Text(book.description)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        .onAppear{
            sortBooksByTitle()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Tested on Xcode 12.3 and run on MacOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Add: `.id(UUID())` to end of `List`